# Segmentation fault in c++ code unable to find reason

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am getting segmentation for the last test case (Don't know what it is ) while solving the problem GREATESC.
Concept of the problem is basic bfs. Given an undirected graph |V| <= 3500 and |E| <= 1000000 
Find the minimum distance between two given vertices.
Here's the problem link http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/GREATESC
Here's my solution link 
http://ideone.com/GqTc6k

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <cassert>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#define Pi 3.14159
#define vi vector<int>
#define pi pair<int,int>
#define si stack<int>

typedef long long int ll;
using namespace std;

bool b[3501][3501]={0};

int main ()
{
    int n,m;
    cin >>n>>m;
    int u,v;
    for (int i  =1;i<= m;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&u);
        scanf("%d",&v);
        b[u][v]=b[v][u]=1;
    }
    // input completed.
    int dist[n+1];

    int h,V;
    cin >>h>>V;
    dist[h]=0;
    //cout<<"hero "<<h<<" "<<V<<endl;
    queue<int> q;
    bool  bfs[3501];
    for (int  i=1;i<= n;i++)bfs[i]=1;
    q.push(h);
    bfs[h]=0;
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        int top = q.front();
       // cout<<top<<endl;
        q.pop();
        for (int i = 1 ;i <= 3500;i++)
        {
            if(bfs[i] && b[i][top])
            {
                int x = i;
                dist[i] = dist[top] +1;
                if(x == V){cout<<dist[x]<<endl;return 0;}
                bfs[x]=0;
                q.push(x);
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<0<<endl;
}
```

Comment: What do you have against index 0?  :)

Comment: add more logs to your code, so you may understand where is Segmentation Fault rising from

Comment: Run in a debugger, it will stop at the place of the crash. Then you can examine the function call stack, and if needed go up to your code, and there check the values of variables.

Comment: index is greater than 0 @MartinJames so that's not the reason

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
cin >>n>>m;
...
int dist[n+1];
```

Hence the array `dist` may have size less than 3500. But:

```
        for (int i = 1 ;i <= 3500;i++)
           ...
           dist[i] = dist[top] +1;
```

This code might be indexing outside of `dist`.

You seem to need in general to be more careful that when indexing into an array, you're inside the bounds of the array.

Consider using `std::vector` instead of arrays, then [indexing with `at`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) to get bounds checking. Or alternatively, manually `assert` that values are within range:

```
#include <assert.h>
...
        for (int i = 1 ;i <= 3500;i++)
           ...
           assert(i >= 0 && i <= n && top >= 0 && top <= n);
           dist[i] = dist[top] +1;
```

Comment: Actually the mistake is not in that.I tried changing it still i am getting segmentation fault in the 10th test case